# Want to save values each time from for loop

Tags: java, android, for-loop

Below is my code. I am converting images into bytearray values.
Here **finalPathNames.size() == 4** 
So i want to save the byteArray values eachtime like **byteArray1,byteArray2,byteArray3,byteArray4** which is inside **for loop**

```
Set<String> finalPathNames = sharedpre.getStringSet("prePathNames", null);
InputStream is = null;
for (String temp : finalPathNames) {
  try {
    is = new FileInputStream(temp);
    try {
      byteArray  = streamToBytes(is);
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {

  }
}
```

is there any optimized way to find result values

Comment: why you save byte value which may be happen out of memory problem ?

Comment: Please indent your code. Its unreadable now.

Comment: I think an edit is pending approval for exactly that

Comment: To what do you want to save those byte arrays? If you can save the biggest then the number of arrays will not be that important in respect to memory problems.

Comment: @HareshChhelana I want to send images captured from my device as bytes to server. Since we are allowed to use only SOAP. In the sever end it will convert those bytes back to images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the bytes to the server, when you retrieve them or keep them in a list (in case you need them more than 1 time)

```
// as mentioned in the comments, user wants specifically 4 arrays
byte[][] byteArrays = byte[4][]; //

Set<String> finalPathNames = sharedpre.getStringSet("prePathNames", null);
InputStream is = null;
int index = 0;
for (String temp : finalPathNames) {
    byteArrays[index] = new byte[0]; // in case of exception clear array. possibly set to null
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(temp);
        try {
            byte[] byteArray  = streamToBytes(is);
            byteArrays[index] = byteArray;
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { 

    }
    finally {
        index++;
    }
}
```

Then the resulting streams are available as:

```
byteArrays[0], byteArrays[1], byteArrays[2], byteArrays[3],
```

Comment: I am assuming you want to use the byte[] to create images with, in which case it makes most sense to create the images inside the for loop and add the images to a List<...> or Map<String, ...>

Comment: I would post the same answer ;)

Comment: @Joeblade I am getting the location of image from device and converting it to bytes, then sending the bytes to server. I have to do this process for four images

Comment: @Joeblade Hi have you got any idea on this

Comment: @Joeblade I know this way but I have to save the values in different bytes like each time the loop runs have to get the value as byteArray 1, byteArray2, byteArray3, byteArray4

Comment: Are you certain they are always 4? Or can it be a variable number?

Comment: @Joeblade they are always 4 only

Comment: Please update your question to make it clearer what you want. I've updated my answer I think this is what you are asking.